# Sql Import wizard imports 1022868890 as 1.02287e+009

Tags: sql-server-2005, excel, sql-import-wizard

I'm trying to import some data from Excel to SQL Server, I have a TEXT column with some numbers in it, some of the numbers go over just fine, and some turn into scientific form.

Column in Excel is "text" type, column in the target sql table is varchar(255)

Here are some examples:

Excel [text]     -> SQL Server [varchar(255)]
0313852230 -> 0313852230
1024869004 -> 1024869004
1022868890 -> 1.02287e+009
1022868899 -> 1.02287e+009
1022868907 -> 1022868907
1030869319 -> 1030869319
1106869726 -> 1106869726
SomeText   -> SomeText

Please help!

**SOLUTION: Formatting the column as [Number] with 10 leading zeros worked for me, since all my numbers are 10-digit numbers**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: Formatting the column as [Number] with 10 leading zeros worked for me, since all my numbers are 10-digit numbers

Answer (score 0):

You are certain both Excel columns are text and SQL column is VARCHAR?

I know SQL imports into float columns as exponential (which is the correct floating representation)

Comment: There's only 1 Excel column, the numbers on the left are from THE SAME column in Excel, the numbers on the right is the way it imports to SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

When importing to Access, I have found the only column type that works for a straight import of numbers of this type is Zip (Format->Cells->Special->Zip Code). This may also be true with SQL Server.

Comment: Some of the values in the column are text

Comment: I'm using OpenOffice, it doesn't have a Zip data type

Answer (score 0):

Another tip, I prefer to use the SQL Server 2000 tool "Import and Export Data" or "DTS Import/Export Wizard"

This one is way less strict compared to the SQL Server 2005 import tools. Quite often works for me to get data imported in my database.